# Is 'INDEX' valid SQL ANSI ISO standard keyword / reserved word?

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

I've done some research on whether 'INDEX' is a keyword in ANSI SQL but I have not had any luck, especially with the 2008 and the 2011 standard.

Anyone know for sure if this is a valid ANSI ISO SQL keyword?

Comment: From practical point of view the most important is to know if it is a keyword in DBMS you use (though I could think of some exceptions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no ANSI standard for SQL language used to create, alter, or manage indexes.  So no,  INDEX is not a keyword (reserved word) per ANSI standards.

Kevin Kline specifically backs me up here in his book [SQL in a Nutshell](http://books.google.com/books?id=F4dzMjYmLRIC&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=ansi%20create%20index%20statement&source=bl&ots=X3k8YavJam&sig=Gvj2Gtwmn57dmpcXsyRJM9vXat8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IruoT5HGBsGmiQKfubCdAg&ved=0CGMQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=ansi%20create%20index%20statement&f=false).  He points this out as one of the reasons the syntax for creating indexes varies greatly among vendors.

As further circumstantial evidence you'll also note a variety of vendors mention in their SQL documentation that statements regarding INDEXs are extensions to the ANSI standard.  For example see [IBM doc here for ALTER INDEX](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0228.htm).

This is also a [handy list](http://developer.mimer.se/validator/sql-reserved-words.tml) of the ANSI SQL reserved words - but only up to 2003.

---

As a side note: the only time I've ever seen ANSI mentioned at all with regards to indexes is when talking about how a unique index (often simply a unique constraint) treats null values.  According to ANSI a null does not equal a null; therefore a unique index should allow multiple null values since per ANSI they do not equal each other.  Some engines follow this rule - others do not.  The ANSI standard in this case only refers to whether two nulls are equal or unique... the standard has nothing to do with the index.  There may be other ANSI standards that have a similar effect on INDEX but nothing regarding the DDL surrounding them.

Comment: *"Some engines follow this rule - others do not."* Where "others" read "SQL-Server".

Comment: I wasn't sure off the top of my head where Sybase fell on the null!=null issue but MSSQL IS/WAS the primary culprit - though filtered indexes helped (a little).

Comment: Not sure about Sybase either (it may well be in the same trap with SQL-Server in this aspect).

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all the comments. Much appreciated. Closing issue.

Answer (score 2):

Indexes are purposely omitted from the SQL standard because not all data sources that could be targeted using SQL support any concept of 'index'. For example, in MS Access SQL one can use `CREATE TABLE` syntax to create a new MS Excel workbook containing what SQL considers to be a 'table' but which Excel considers to be a 'Named Range' and creating an Access table index on an Excel Range makes no sense.